# Java Pascal's Triangle using this main method to run

Tags: java

I have to implement a code for pascal's triangle using the main code to run it so the main method can't be changed.  However, my program only prints out the first row (1: 1). The only way I can get it to do the full ten rows I need is by altering the main. Any suggestions?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = args.length == 1 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            int[] arr = Pascal.triangle(i);
            System.out.print((i < 10 ? " " : "") + i + ": ");
            for (int j : arr) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

class Pascal{
    public static int[] triangle(int n){
        if(n==1)
            return new int[] {1};
        if(n==2)
            return new int[] {1, 1};
        int[] old = triangle(n-1);
        int[] new1 = new int[old.length+1];
        new1[0] = old[0];
        new1[new1.length-1] = old[old.length-1];
        for(int i=1;i<new1.length-1;i++){
            new1[i] = old[i-1] + old[i];
        }
        return new1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a homework-esque post; in which case, you should specify as a tag or at the top or bottom of the post body.  There are specific SO rules for homework questions

Answer (score 1):

`main` is expecting a command-line argument to tell it how many lines to print, so you need to learn how to pass that argument in your particular working environment.  In Netbeans IDE, for instance, you can specify command-line arguments as part of your project settings.

A simple work-around, just for testing purposes, would be to add this line at the top of `main`:

```
    args = new String[]{"10"};
```

Comment: Oh okay, is there a way to do this without making an edit to the main method or would that require a different work around?

Comment: @MattSchumacher, If you want to be old school, use a terminal and type `java Main 10` (for cli arguments in an IDE, Google.  I really don't know how to do cli arguments in an IDE).  

Also, I tested it, and this is the issue

Comment: Your instructor must know how to run your program with a command-line argument, so if the program works satisfactorily for with my hack in place, it will work satisfactorily for the instructor with the hack gone.

Comment: The easiest thing I found to do was to change the last 1 in line 4 with a 10 and that prints out the ten lines.  I guess that would be acceptable.

Comment: @MattSchumacher that'll work too; for me it's just easier to add a line of code that can be commented out with // or deleted when it's no longer needed.  _Chaqun a son goût_, as they say...